# binding a gridvidew

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

in my ASP.NET 3.5 web application, I like to bind data in a grid or any other tabular format whcih supports editing and saving the records on the fly.
Other than Ajax (Updatepanals) do you have any other solution?? Reason for not using the updatepanal, as my website is having huge amount of data on the page. I dont want any postback.

Comment: Why do you have so much data on the screen? its like putting a million records in a datagrid, is it usable?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a client-side grid like jqGrid. http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Comment: @Chetan - you can support all CRUD methods by hooking the grid up to `WebServices` or `PageMethods`